# how to create own client for Oauth2 for angular js for grant_type code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oauth-2.0, django-rest-framework

I am trying to implement Oauth2 for my application. For server side its completely done. 
My scenario is 
I want to provide my own api's like twitter and facebook do. The normal procedure of Oauth2 is imlemented properly on server i.e.

1. user need to create one application on my developer console
2. After that he will get client_id and client_secret
3. get the accesstoken usint "code", "client_credentials" or "password"
4. use this accesstoken to access API's.

This flow is done.

```
Ex.To get code
http://localhost:8000/api/rest/rest-auth/o/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=391279895fa4bf4fcbddcd953dfe0d48&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8000/api/rest/email

Result is {"code":"5YH2ccrExsknqUrmFerMgfzriCXda1"}
```

And using this code i am getting access_token.

My main concern is that my client is in angular js. What i am not getting here that how to get the access_token using grant_type "code".

I am able to get the access_token using grant_type "client_credentials" from my angular application.

But here i am not able to get how to show popup window to user to grant access to get access_token from angular application and get response back to my client app.
From my understanding facebook and google has there own client.js i.e. clients from which they manage these requests.

What should be my approach here. Provide any useful links if available.
I want to implement Oauth for my own apis not foe google and facebook.

Comment: Using client side application and frameworks, it's not good at all to store secret on client side (security issues) . The fact is that authorization code is not a good idea.
You should use implicit grant flow instead.

Comment: thank you. Can you provide some links which will have the same information.

Comment: https://aaronparecki.com/2012/07/29/2/oauth2-simplified

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2